# Spring validation is not throwing any error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-validator

I tried every possible way to fix it but I failed. So, I have my controller working and I have also written code to handle validation but It is not throwing any error even if I send some invalid data.I have just applied @notNull and @notEmpty validation for now to just test.Here is my code. Please help me to find out what is wrong with it ?

**registerForm.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addRegistration" commandName="regForm">

   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name : </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        <td align="left"><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age : </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
        <td align="left"><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email">Email : </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        <td align="left"><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="refer">Refer : </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="refer" /></td>
        <td align="left"><form:errors path="refer" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

**SpringFormDem-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="registration" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />

    </bean>

 <bean id="myBeansValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
</beans>
```

**RegisterationController.java**

```
@Controller
public class RegistartionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/registrationForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registrationForm(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("regForm", new RegistationDetails()); 
        //return new ModelAndView("registrationForm", "command", new RegistationDetails());
        return "registrationForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRegistration(@ModelAttribute("regForm") @Valid RegistationDetails register, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
    {
        String ret;
        System.out.println(result.toString());
      if(result.hasErrors())
      {
          ret = "registrationForm";
      }
      else
      {
        model.addAttribute("name", register.getName());
          model.addAttribute("age", register.getAge());
          model.addAttribute("email", register.getEmail());
          model.addAttribute("refer", register.getRefer());

      ret = "displayResult";
      }
      return ret;

   }
}
```

**RegistartionDetail.java**

```
public class RegistationDetails {

    @NotNull(message = "Your name can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Your name can not be null")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Your email can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Your email can not be null")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Your refer can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Your refer can not be null")
    private String refer;

    @NotNull(message = "Your age can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Your age can not be null")
    private String age;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the refer
     */
    public String getRefer() {
        return refer;
    }

    /**
     * @param refer the refer to set
     */
    public void setRefer(String refer) {
        this.refer = refer;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION :**

From the comment I found out that my configuration file was missing :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

When I added this line to the code then it threw me an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 30; The prefix "mvc" for element
>   "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound

To solve this error I required to add few lines to configuration file :

```
<beans 
   ...
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   ...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? and are you sure that null or empty data is passing to backend?? and have you checked `binding result(result)` object what it contains??

Comment: Yes, my "displayresult.jsp" is displaying empty value which I read data from object returned which contains the data entered by a user in the registration page.
I tried to see if there is any error or not so I just called toString() method as System.out.println(result.toString()), but it always returns org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors.

Comment: If you have data in the object than how come `NotNull` or `NotEmpty` can be true? Don't enter anything for `name` field..then `RegistationDetails(regiater)` object it should show null to name field and then check result object it has to show @NotNull error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

Here is the solution that worked for me.

From the comment I found out that my configuration file was missing :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

When I added this line to the code then it threw me an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 30; The prefix "mvc" for element
>   "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound

To solve this error I required to add few lines to configuration file :

```
<beans 
   ...
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   ...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a bindingresult to inspect if there are errors.
A quick google gave me this example:
http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

Comment: I have that in my controller. public String addRegistration(@ModelAttribute("regForm") @Valid RegistationDetails register, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)

Comment: Do you have an mvc:annotation-driven (or an `@EnableWebMVC`  config?). Also, see what @Sam says in his comment.

Comment: when I add <mvc:annotation-driven /> , it gives me an error as follow : Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 30; The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Answer (score 0):

from first inspection of your code how are you passing your details to be validated, looking at your form you are not setting the text fields for the user to pass any values.....if i run your form in text editor no fields are present, have you tried setting setting the input type to text. type="text"

e.g...

Comment: <form:input type="text" path="name"/>